# I want to convert a single json event into multiple events, through logstash Hope to get some inspiration, thanks

Tags: ruby, logstash

4 fields (warnTags、warnSlrs、warnActions、denyMsg) fields need to be separated by semicolon(;)

**Raw String**

```
   { "waf": {
    "warnTags": "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION;OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS;OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS;OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS;OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SPECIAL_CHARS;OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION",
    "policy": "bot_77598",
    "warnSlrs": "ARGS:wvstest;ARGS:wvstest;ARGS:wvstest;ARGS:wvstest;ARGS:wvstest;ARGS:wvstest",
    "riskTuples": ":-973305-973333-973335",
    "warnActions": "2;2;2;2;2;2",
    "denyActions": "3",
    "warnMsg": "SQL Injection Attack;XSS Attack Detected;IE XSS Filters - Attack Detected;IE XSS Filters - Attack Detected;Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded;Classic SQL Injection Probes 1/2",
    "riskGroups": ":XSS-ANOMALY",
    "warnRules": "950901;973305;973333;973335;981173;981242",
    "denyMsg": "Anomaly Score Exceeded for Cross-Site Scripting",
    "ver": "2.0",
    "denyData": "VmVjdG9yIFNjb3JlOiBx",
    "riskScores": ":-5-5-2",
    "warnData": "eHNzdGFnPigpbG9jeHNz;amF2YXNYcm"
} }
```

**Expected Output Result**

```
{
    "waf": {
        "warnTags": "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION",
        "policy": "bot_77598",
        "warnSlrs": "ARGS:wvstest",
        "riskTuples": ":-973305-973333-973335",
        "warnActions": "2",
        "denyActions": "3",
        "warnMsg": "SQL Injection Attack",
        "riskGroups": ":XSS-ANOMALY",
        "warnRules": "950901",
        "denyMsg": "Anomaly Score Exceeded for Cross-Site Scripting",
        "ver": "2.0",
        "denyData": "VmVjdG9yIFNjb3JlOiBx",
        "riskScores": ":-5-5-2",
        "warnData": "eHNzdGFnPigpbG9jeHNz;amF2YXNYcm"
    }
}

{
    "waf": {
        "warnTags": "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS",
        "policy": "bot_77598",
        "warnSlrs": "ARGS:wvstest",
        "riskTuples": ":-973305-973333-973335",
        "warnActions": "2",
        "denyActions": "3",
        "warnMsg": "XSS Attack Detected",
        "riskGroups": ":XSS-ANOMALY",
        "warnRules": "973305",
        "denyMsg": "Anomaly Score Exceeded for Cross-Site Scripting",
        "ver": "2.0",
        "denyData": "VmVjdG9yIFNjb3JlOiBx",
        "riskScores": ":-5-5-2",
        "warnData": "eHNzdGFnPigpbG9jeHNz;amF2YXNYcm"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the article here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Ensuring your question is well structured will help to get the best responses in future. I've had a stab below at a config which should get you going. Best of luck and happy elking.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter {
ruby {
    code => "
        @info = []
        events = event.to_hash
        @warnTags = events['waf']['warnTags'].split(';')
        @warnMsgs = events['waf']['warnMsg'].split(';')
        @warnActions = events['waf']['warnActions'].split(';')
        @warnRules = events['waf']['warnRules'].split(';')

        @list = @warnTags.zip( @warnMsgs, @warnActions, @warnRules )
        @list.each do |tag, msg, action, rule|
            detail = {
                'tag' => tag,
                'msg' => msg,
                'action' => action,
                'rule' => rule
            }
            @info.push(detail)
        end

        event.remove('[waf][warnTags]')
        event.remove('[waf][warnMsg]')
        event.remove('[waf][warnActions]')
        event.remove('[waf][warnRules]')
        event.set('[waf][info]', @info)
    "
}

split {
    field => "[waf][info]"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The config below should be along the lines of what you need. It includes parsing as json at the outset which you may not need depending on prior steps in your pipeline. Essentially this will split the `warnTags` field on `;` to begin with; that will result in `warnTags` being an array nested within one object. The output of the string split is passed in the to higher level `split` filter which will create multiple output events splitting on input field, in this case `warnTags` (again). Hope this helps!

[EDIT: Added `warnSlrs` as second split field]

```
filter {
       json {
            source => "message"
       }
       mutate {
              split => {"[waf][warnTags]" => ";"}
       }
       mutate {
              split => {"[waf][warnSlrs]" => ";"}
       }
       split {
              field => "[waf][warnTags]"
       }
       split {
              field => "[waf][warnSlrs]"
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer，But I still don't know how to split more than 2 fields at the same time, although their delimiters are all semicolons（;）

Comment: Ok, I've added `warnSlrs`, hope you can see how to extend further now :)

Comment: **Thank you very much for your continued help, but I found that 36 events have been generated after this processing. I expect that in this example, one event will generate 6 events and one field can be split to generate 6 events using split, but multiple fields Split will generate a lot of unwanted events, and maybe need to use ruby to handle my needs**

Comment: Ah, I assumed you wanted the cross product in terms of output.